# Problem with total amount in IF statement

Tags: python, if-statement, nested, pycharm

I'm new to coding and I want to understand nested IF statements. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, the # total amount is what I am struggling with since I am not getting an answer from PyCharm. Much appreciated for those who could help me.

```
# Dogfood bags in 3 pack sizes and their cost
l = 100
m = 70
s = 40

# Basic questions
size = input("Bag size 20kg(L), 15kg(M), 5kg(S): ")
type = input("For adult dog or puppy dog (A/P): ")

if size.lower() in "l":
    q = input("How many bags of Large size bags? ")
elif size.lower() in "m":
    q = input("How many bags of Medium size bags? ")
elif size.lower() in "s":
    q = input("How many bags of Small size bags? ")

print("*************")

# Finalize output
if type.lower() in "a":
    print(f"Food Type: Adult")
elif type.lower() in "p":
    print(f"Food Type: Puppy")

if size.lower() in "l":
    print(f"Bag size: Large")
elif size.lower() in "m":
    print(f"Bag size: Medium")
elif size.lower() in "s":
    print(f"Bag size: Small")

print(f"Number of bags: {q}")
print()

# Total amount cost

if size.lower() == "l":
    if type.lower() == "a":
        print(f"Total amount with delivery ${q * l}")
    elif type.lower() == "p":
        print(f"Total amount with delivery ${int(q * l) - 5}")

elif size.lower() == "m":
    if type.lower() == "a":
        print(f"Total amount with delivery ${q * l}")
    elif type.lower() == "p":
        print(f"Total amount with delivery ${int(q * l) - 5}")

elif size.lower() == "s":
    if type.lower() == "a":
        print(f"Total amount with delivery ${q * l}")
    elif type.lower() == "p":
        print(f"Total amount with delivery ${int(q * l) - 5}")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question it should have no more code than the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem by copy-pasting, a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Hey it might help people answer your question if you could be more specific with the trouble you are running into. I ran your code and figured out pretty quickly what the problem is. Your IF statements all seemed to work as intended, I found that the only thing that seemed to be wrong with the code is that the total amounts would be way off what I would imagine they should be. In python when you multiply a string by an integer
Ex:

```
> value = "1" * 5
```

The output is the string repeated the integer amount of times, the in the case above  `value` would be equal to `"11111"`. The problem with your program is that the `input()` function only returns strings, even if all the characters are numbers. In your case, the `q` variable is a string all the way until the end of the code. A simple fix to this would be using the `int()` function, casting the variable to be type `integer` instead of `string`.

```
size = "Small"
q = input(f"How many bags of {size} size bags? ")
q = int(q)
```

Now if you were to do that same thing as done above with the `value` variable, the output would be:

```
> size = "Small"
> q = input(f"How many bags of {size} size bags? ")
How many bags of Small size bags? 2
> q = int(q)
> print(q * 5)
10
```

Also something to keep in mind is that using the variable name `type` is very bad practice as it is also the name of a function that tells you the data type of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of solving the bug for you, I'll try and cover a valuable lesson for life.

Instead of doing multiple conditions to change a single word (Large, Medium, Small) in a question, just store the right word once in a variable and reuse it unconditionally.
The code will become much much simpler:

```
sizes = {
  'l': ('Large', 100)
  'm': ('Medium', 70)
  's': ('Small', 40)
}
size = input("Bag size 20kg(L), 15kg(M), 5kg(S): ")
size = size.lower()
if size not in sizes.keys():
  print('Wrong bag size')
  return
size_description, size_price = sizes[size]
print(f"Bag size: {size_description}")

types = {
  'a': 'Adult',
  'p': 'Puppy'
}
type = input("For adult dog or puppy dog (A/P): ")
type = type.lower()
if size not in types.keys():
  print('Wrong type')
  return
type_description = types[size]
print(f"Food type: {type_description}")

quantity = input(f"How many bags of {size_description} size? ")
quantity = int(quantity)
print(f"Number of bags: {quantity}")

total_price = quantity * size_price
if type == 'a':
  total_price -= 5
```

Now, let's discuss the changes:

- You never check for the same condition twice, which makes the code much much simpler to understand and maintain
- I added some checks, because your code would fail if the users specifies something other than `l/m/s` or `a/p`
- Instead of repeating conditions over and over again, we use a dictionary to map user inputs to expected values without using conditions
- Rearranged prints to be next to the value they depend on. That's a styling decision, but I would advise on taking
- As some1and2 correctly pointed out, you have to cast `quantity` to get it to work correctly

Hope that helps.